# Strict validation of DTO in Spring Boot request body

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have a Spring Boot RestController like this

```
public class MyRestController{

 @RequestMapping(value = "/resources", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Created",
            response = Resource.class) })
    @ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.CREATED )
    public Resource createResource(@RequestBody Resource res){
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)
public class Resource{
  private String resourceName;
  private int value;
}
```

When I pass a json like this :

```
{
   "unknownProperty": "test",
   "value::100
}
```

I want an exception to be thrown since I have set @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false) but this is not happening. What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that ignored properties are meant to be ignored silently. If you specifically want to throw an exception on properties you're not expecting to see, then create a custom deserializer and ask your type to be serialized with it eg

`@JsonDeserialize(using = MyCustomDeserializer.class)` (on your type).

I believe your custom deserializer will need to extend `JsonDeserializer<MyType>`

To get the deserialization failure you're looking for you'll need to override `deserialize()` and in that create an object mapper and configure it as follows.

`objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);`

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a bean to configure ObjectMapper:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
    return om;
}
```